# nginx delete location not found URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

By default, nginx returns an HTML page when a URL is specified that does not match any of the paths, and returns a 404. Is there a way to remove the HTML page generated and just return a 404 status code? I looked into the error_page directive but that seems to force you to have to specify a different HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `error_page` to specify an empty file. In which case the `Content-Length` is zero and the `Content-Type` is based on the file's extension.

For example:

```
error_page 404 /empty.txt;
```